# Constructing shapely Points from pandas series

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, pandas

I am new to geospatial analysis including geopandas and shapely. My requirement is to do a point in a polygon operation using a spark dataframe and pandas UDF (for performance reasons). The spark dataframe contains the lat and lon and the polygon is in a csv file with a column called `geom_str` of type `geometry`. I am able to construct the gdf(GeoDataFrame) successfully from the csv file.
The UDF looks like this

```
def find_segment_pandas(latitude: pd.Series, longitude: pd.Series) -> pd.Series: 
    mgdf = gdf.apply(lambda x: x['id'] if x['geom_str'].contains(Point(latitude, longitude)) else None, axis=1)
    idx = mgdf.first_valid_index()
    first_valid_value = mgdf.loc[idx] if idx is not None else "N/A"
    return pd.Series(first_valid_value)
```

When I call this from a spark dataframe, it gives me a type error that it can't convert pandas series to a float object. I understand that it is coming from the `Point` constructor but I haven't been able to figure out how I should convert the incoming series of lat and lon to corresponding floating types for Point to work.

Comment: I assume that `gdf` is a GeoDataFrame, and the `"geom_str"` column has `Polygon` shapely geometries, right? Have you checked to make sure that there aren't rows where that column has `NA`, `None` or `Empty Geometry` values?